# cannot obtain authoryear-style citation call-outs with the 'natbib' package

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using natbib package and plainnat style. I need to create citation call-outs of the "Author et al. (2000)".

In preamble, I have `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`.

In the text, I use `\citet{ref}`. This is supposed to generate "Author et al. (2000)".

The problem is that natbib refuses to show such citation; instead, it shows just `(1)`. However, if I write `\citeauthor{ref} \citeyearpar{ref}` it's ok: "Author et al. (2000)".

What is the problem? It seems that natbib just ignores the command \citet

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be great if you could form your code snippets into an MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The `plainnat` bibliography style, when used in conjunction with the `natbib` citation management package, is definitely capable of producing authoryear-style citation call-outs. Something must be going on in your code that's changing the citation call-out style from authoryear to numeric. Some, not mutually exclusive, hypotheses:

- Do you and/or the document class you employ maybe load the natbib package more than once, with conflicting options? In particular, is the `numbers` option specified in any of the duplicate `natbib` loading operations?
- Are there any `\setcitestyle` instructions after the `natbib` package is loaded?
- Are there any `\bibpunct` instructions after the `natbib` package is loaded?
- Is there more than one `\bibliographystyle` instruction in the document?

A quick-and-dirty fix for re-instating authoryear-style citation call-outs would be to insert the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{authoryear}
```

immediately before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: this is what i use in the preambule

Comment: \newfloat{algorithm}{H}{}
\sloppy
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.5cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{1.20\textwidth}
\setlength{\textheight}{1.25\textheight}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\fi
\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

Comment: \newtheorem{observ}{Observation}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newcommand{\proof}{
\noindent
{\bf Proof: }}
\newcommand{\qed}{ \hspace*{\fill} \rule{1ex}{1ex}

Comment: \newcommand{\qed}{ \hspace*{\fill} \rule{1ex}{1ex}
\noindent}
\input{tcilatex}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm}

Comment: In fact insted of Borthen et al. (2017) it produces Borthen et al. (2)

Comment: I use \citet{ref}

Comment: It somehow ignores theyear citation althoug it is indicated authoryear. There are options of between the number and the year. I use

Comment: As well itried \citealp{ref} and insted Author et al., 2000 it produces 2

Comment: @Yauheni - which document class do you use?

Comment: @Yauheni - Please don't post code snippets in comments. Instead, please edit your original query to provide the relevant preamble code. That way, (a) many more potential readers will see it and (b) it can be pretty-printed much more easily.